# Logstash configuration error and I think this a dumb question

Tags: logstash

I am trying to get logstash to work (well I have gotten it to work but I want to try growing my skill set) and this is my config file setup...

```
    input {
      file {
        path => "C:/temp/Machine Learning/Dash.txt"
        start_position => "beginning"
        sincedb_path => "/tmp/since.txt"
      }
    }

    filter {

      json { 
                source => "message" 
                target => "message" 
            }
    }

    output {
       file {path => "/tmp/OutPut.txt"}
    }
```

What I want to do is parse out the message field and look at its constituent pieces, but this config doesn't work. I get this when I run it in debug...

> Missing a required setting for the json filter plugin:

```
  filter {
    json {
      source => # SETTING MISSING
      ...
    }
  }
```

> [2019-12-19T10:32:44,655][ERROR][logstash.agent           ] Failed to execute action {:action=>LogStash::PipelineAction::Create/pipeline_id:main, :exception=>"LogStash::ConfigurationError", :message=>"Something is wrong with your configuration.", :backtrace=>["c:/Logstash/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/config/mixin.rb:86:in `config_init'", "c:/Logstash/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/filters/base.rb:126:in`initialize'", "org/logstash/plugins/PluginFactoryExt.java:70:in `filter_delegator'", "org/logstash/plugins/PluginFactoryExt.java:244:in`plugin'", "org/logstash/plugins/PluginFactoryExt.java:181:in `plugin'", "c:/Logstash/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:71:in`plugin'", "(eval):64:in `<eval>'", "org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:994:in`eval'", "c:/Logstash/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:49:in `initialize'", "c:/Logstash/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:90:in`initialize'", "c:/Logstash/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/pipeline_action/create.rb:42:in `block in execute'", "c:/Logstash/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/agent.rb:92:in`block in exclusive'", "org/jruby/ext/thread/Mutex.java:148:in `synchronize'", "c:/Logstash/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/agent.rb:92:in`exclusive'", "c:/Logstash/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/pipeline_action/create.rb:38:in `execute'", "c:/Logstash/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/agent.rb:317:in`block in converge_state'"]}

And I am not sure what to do about that as it looks like I have set up the filter right according to this documentation:

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-json.html#plugins-filters-json-target

I am on windows 10 which I think is important info.

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem. Like the professional that I am I made a back up config file to revert back to incase something went awry, great idea honestly. Then like the idiot I am I started making updates and changes to the backup file which was not the actually config file I was testing against.